# Results unstable data in Azure Databricks notebook using spark.sql()

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm creating a notebook in azure databricks, here I've found one unnatural and unstable behavior of data which is returned from query executed by spark.sql()

For example, I'm having a DataFrame with single-integer(not null) column. So, that I've also created a tempview from the same DataFrame using **createOrReplaceTempView()**

Now when I'm querying with **where** condition using spark.sql, it returned me data for one integer  but not for another. As Cmd 15, except line#5 query all other are giving me correct result.
[image]

and unlikely, below is the result of line#5

[image]

We've also tried with DataFrame's filter, where etc. But no luck.
[image]

Comment: why don't you convert statusId to int or number and filter ?

Comment: Thanks @dsk, actually we already tried that but no luck. And why it is not working with one integer number but working with another that is the biggest question here. I'm updating my question to satisfy your suggestion/doubt.

Comment: This is quite strange - How does other API is performing - Spark - Scala or Pyspark ?

Comment: @dsk, Yes it is.  All other are working absolutely fine.